# Delphi 7 on Windows 8.1

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have just finished installing delphi 7 on my laptop and when I tried to make a form and run it. An error pops up and says [Fatal Error] Could not create output file 'D:\Delphi7SE\Projects\Project1.exe'. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: twice so that free CodeTyphon can legally offer you next to anything home user of Delphi 7 might like

Comment: It sounds like you may already be running this application outside of the IDE.

Comment: @JerryDodge that may be antivirus also. Sometime I have a similar thing in xe2 under win10x64 - but wait a second and two and next compilation attempt goes fine.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I do not see in edit history claims that D7 was pirated. While it definitely can be the case I wonder if that was your guess or the stated fact.

Comment: @Arioch'The, I think the Delphi7**SE** gives a clue...

Comment: Yup, SE is the tell.

Comment: @kobik maybe, but I also typically install Delphi outside "program files". And D7 was out 3 years after win98SE, so while it was possible that pirats used part of hyped "win98se" brand for their d7 bundle, still it is just a possibility. Afterall why would those pirats even bother to modify the standard installer ???

Comment: @Arioch'The: Maybe some included readme.txt advises to install the program outside "Program Files" to avoid the usual UAC issues. And maybe it used `D:\Delphi7SE\` as example path.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What does "SE" mean for Delphi 7? My only guess is "second edition" - why does it indicate piracy?

Comment: @David Do a web search. There's a well known pirate version that goes by that moniker

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I searched, and saw plenty of download links, but also that they were all called "Second Edition". I didn't realise Borland didn't make a second edition (if that's what you're implying?) and so SE is a, what, user/pirate-created edition?

Comment: +davidm it's not a Borland release, it's a pirated version

Comment: can someone explain why my antivirus is preventing me from running a form?

Comment: Your AV software has probably recognised that you have illicit software. Perhaps the cracked software came with an actual virus. Why are you using cracks?

Comment: @JaneDoe use legal free CodeTyphon - it has next to all D7 features you may really need at home. If you use pirated D7 then you already see you got more problems with it than you can solve

Comment: @Arioch'The Of course, then there's the issue of the PilotLogic / CodeTyphon GPL violations .........

Comment: @DavidHeffernan now GPL violation too ? I only heard about GLScene/VGScene/FMX dispute

Comment: okay, there was some issue with GPL too but seems minor and resolved half a year ago - http://wiki.freepascal.org/codetyphon

Comment: thanks for all the help guys, i really appreciate it

Comment: please help again, after disabling my antivirus it worked the first time but after a few tries. The error is back please help :(

Comment: what do you guys think is happening? :(

Comment: It would be nice to know how you solved it for future users

Comment: i just restarted my pc

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, that you have access rights in that folder. For testing, try to run Delphi with administrtor rights.